# Use SQL Server CE Locally and SQL Server 2008 on Production Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF Code first to generate my models.  I have added SQL Server Compact Edition to my project and am using that as a DB locally.

I want to configure the DataContext so that when I push to Production (based on the machine name) it instead would pull from a connection string in the Web Config and use a SQL Server 2008 DB.

What is the easiest way to do this?  Basically my question is at what point do I need to add the conditional so that when it is deployed it pulls in the connection string and just works.

Is this even a recommended approach?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you only need to deliver a different ConnectionString when you deploy your App.Config

Using different 'Solution Configurations' (Debug/Release/ etc.) there are possibilities to even automate this via with MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488227/choose-settings-based-on-machine-name) discussion has one approach where you have multiple settings in the same config file.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414630/how-do-you-set-up-solution-configuration-specific-config-files) the suggestion is to use multiple config files, one for each environment or use MSBuild to produce select a config file.

using `#IF DEBUG` is another option but risky where a developer decides to test a release version and forgets they are running against a live system!